# Use success value of `if let` in SwiftUI 3

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift5

I have this check in SwiftUI

```
 if tasks.first(where: { task in
            return isDone(task)
        }) != nil {
            let task = tasks.first(where: { task in
                    return isDone(task) 
                }
            )
```

I'm wondering if there's a way in SwiftUI 3 to use `task` from the check, instead of having to redefine it in the success block?

I've tried replacing the first line with `if let task = tasks.first ....` but it returns a Bool, which makes sense.

Not really sure what this is called so don't know what else to research.

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with `if let`?

Comment: Yup, if let _does_ work, I was just checking that it wasn't null != null so it defaulted to a Bool, but taking that out and using `$0.isDone` works with `if let` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted something like this (simplified):

```
struct Task {
    var isDone: Bool {
        true
    }
    var name = "test"
}
func foo() {
    let tasks = [Task(), Task()]

    // just don't use `!= nil` converting it to Bool
    if let task = tasks.first(where: { $0.isDone }) {
        print(task.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect. I was checking that it wasn't null `!= null` so it defaulted to a Bool (i assume) 

Thank you! Learned something new.